# How to disable Flow (JS) type checking for a single line

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, flowtype

Some of my unit tests involve passing invalid (improperly typed) data to a function. For example:

```
// user.js

type User = {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    email: string
}

export function validateUser(user: User): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // resolve if user is valid, reject if not
    })
}
```

```
// user.unit.js

import {validateUser} from '../user.js' 

describe('validateUser', () => {
    it('should reject if user is not valid', () => {
        const invalidUser: User = {}
        expect(validateUser(invalidUser)).to.be.rejected
    })
})
```

Since the `invalidUser` variable does not conform to the `User` type, I get a flow error:

```
Cannot call validateUser with invalidUser bound to user because:
 • property id is missing in object literal [1] but exists in User [2].
 • property name is missing in object literal [1] but exists in User [2].
 • property email is missing in object literal [1] but exists in User [2].
```

Obviously I want this variable to be invalid, so how can I disable flow type checking for this single instance?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [.flowconfig [options] docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options), there is an option to specify a [suppress comment](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex). Flow will detect this comment and ignore the following line of code.

By default:

> If no suppression comments are specified in your config, Flow will apply one default: `// $FlowFixMe`.

So just add a comment (`$FlowFixMe`) to suppress type checking for a single line.

```
// $FlowFixMe
const invalidUser: User = {}
```

Comment: Option `suppress_comment` has been [deprecated](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex) since Flow 0.127.0: *"In version v0.127.0, the option to specify the suppression comment syntax was removed. $FlowFixMe, $FlowIssue, $FlowExpectedError, and $FlowIgnore became the only standard suppressions."*